# I have this Error - jquery.min.js: 2 Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation django

Tags: django, ajax

I am trying to save the order details data, however I get this error.

```
jquery.min.js: 2 Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
```

I am still in the process of sending that data to the database, I just want to see if it is working correctly with this line of code:

```
vents = request.POST['ventas']
```

JS

```
    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var parametros = new FormData();
        parametros.append('action', $('input[name="action"]').val());
        parametros.append('ventas', JSON.stringify(ventas.items));
        submit(window.location.pathname, parametros, function(){
            location.href = "{% url 'Venta' %}";

        });
    });
```

VIEWS

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = {}
        try:
            action = request.POST['action']
            if action == 'autocomplete':
                productos = Producto.objects.filter(nombre__icontains=request.POST['term'])[0:10]
                for i in productos:
                    data = []
                    item = i.toJSON()
                    item['value'] = i.nombre
                    data.append(item)
            elif action == 'add':
                vents = request.POST['ventas']
            else:
                data['error'] = 'No ha ingresado a ninguna opción'
        except Exception as e:
            data['error'] = str(e) 
        return JsonResponse(data,safe=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

**In your js do:**

```js
       $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var parametros = new FormData();
        parametros.append('action', $('input[name="action"]').val());
        parametros.append('ventas', JSON.stringify(ventas.items));
        submit(window.location.pathname, parametros, function(){
            location.href = "{% url 'Venta' %}";

        });
    })
```

Just get rid of the trailing ';' at the last ')' closing.Worked for me when I run into this problem!